# how to end sessions in code igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

i created login with sessions recently in code igniter. it logged in successfully but i forgot to put a logout. i accidentally clicked back, then i got this error,,

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare login_model::validate() in C:\xampp\htdocs\HR\application\models\login_model.php on line 41
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Compile Error

Message: Cannot redeclare login_model::validate()

Filename: models/login_model.php

Line Number: 41

Backtrace:
```

then when i go back to the original page http://localhost/hr/login/index1
i also get that error. how can i stop the session of this? and why is the session dont go inside my database ci_sessions.

Comment: The error message reads like a different problem than what you're saying. Looks like a duplicate method name, not a Session issue

Comment: // for log-in

 `public function validateCreds(){

  $this->load->model('login_model');
  $q = $this->login_model->validate();

  if ($q == 1){

   if($q){ //if creds are validated

    $data = array(

     'USERNAME' => $this->input->post('USERNAME'),
     'is_logged_in' => true
    );



    $this->session->set_userdata($data);
    redirect('login/index1');

   }else{ //incorrect username or password

   $this ->index();
   }
  
  }
 }`

Comment: //login_model

 `public function validate($USERNAME, $PASSWORD){

  $sql ="SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE USERNAME = ? AND PASSWORD = ?";
  $data1 = array(
   'USERNAME' => $this->input->post('USERNAME'),
   'PASSWORD' => $this->input->post('PASSWORD')
   );
  $query = $this->db->query($sql, $data1);

  //$username = $this->db->where('USERNAME', $this->input->post('USERNAME'));
  //$this->db->where('PASSWORD', $this->input->post('PASSWORD'));
  //$query = $this->db->get('tbl_users');

  
  return $query->num_rows();
  
 }`

Comment: "Looks like a duplicate method name, not a Session issue" @DamienPirsy yes. your right. haha. i copied the validate function twice. haha. but yet i got another problem. my login function and log-out function looks like they're just links. when i click login then click back button, i automatically log out, and when i click forward, it logs in without having to enter anything

Comment: It looks like you have the function validate twice in your model.

Answer (score 0):

You can destroy session by:-

```
$this->session->sess_destroy();
```

If you logout then although the session is destroyed, the session userdata remains for the duration of the current CI page build.

You should make a function like below.

```
function log_out()
{
    $this->session->sess_destroy();
    // null the session (just in case):
    $this->session->set_userdata(array('user_name' => '', 'is_logged_in' => ''));    
    redirect('your_page_url');
}
```

There is the function to destroy some session you want

```
   $this->session->unset_userdata('session_name');
```

Comment: i made that one but i cannot access the log-out bec. the page where the logout button doesnot show.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function logout() {
    $this->session->unset_userdata();
    $this->session->unset_userdata('is_client_login');
    $this->session->sess_destroy();
    $this->output->set_header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, no-transform, max-age=0, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    $this->output->set_header("Pragma: no-cache");
    redirect($this->getUrl('/'));
}
```